# C# create instance of the derived class in the base class

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I have the following set up:

```
public abstract class A
{
    public void f()
    {
        //Want to make an instance of B or C here
        //A bOrC = new ?
    }
    public abstract void f2();
}
public class B : A { public override void f2(){} }
public class C : A { public override void f2(){} }
```

Is this possible? If so how?

**Edit:** `bOrC` needs to be the type of the particular derived class `f()` is called from

Comment: Sure, you can `new B()` or `new C()` - is there something specific in your context that makes this not possible?

Comment: I think the point is that an instance of B or C is required, but which of these types is not known at the point of the call.

Comment: Is the f() method to make a copy of the current instance or something - ie to make a new instance of the child type?

Comment: can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Perhaps this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368643/how-do-i-create-clone-of-object-in-base-class

Comment: Jon Egerton is correct. I have modified the question to hopefully clarify.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can think of two ways to solve this issue. One uses generics and the other just requires an abstract method. First the simple one.

```
public abstract class A
{
    public void f()
    {
        A bOrC = newInstance();
    }
    public abstract void f2();
    protected abstract A newInstance();
}
public class B : A {
    public override void f2(){}
    public override A newInstance(){
        return new B();
    }
}
public class C : A {
    public override void f2(){}
    public override A newInstance(){
        return new C();
    }
}
```

And now with generics

```
public abstract class A<T> where T : A, new()
{
    public void f()
    {
        A bOrC = new T();
    }
    public abstract void f2();
}
public class B : A<B> {
    public override void f2(){}
}
public class C : A<C> {
    public override void f2(){}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had thought of your first method, but wondered if there was a neater way of doing it using things like `this.GetType()`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Activator.CreateInstance(this.GetType());`

Comment: It wasn't me that down voted, but I would then need to cast the object it returns into `B` or `C` without knowing which one. It doesn't solve my problem

Comment: You can just cast it to A, and you'll have everything you would be able to do the other way as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, and would lead to some weird consequences if it was. However, there is an easy work around rendering code that is easy to read.

```
public abstract class A
{
    public void f()
    {
        //Want to make an instance of B or C here
        //A bOrC = new ?
        A bOrC = Create();
    }
    public abstract void f2();
    public abstract A Create();
}
public class B : A {
  public override void f2(){}
  public override A Create() { return new B(); }
}
public class C : A {
  public override void f2(){}
  public override A Create() { return new C(); }
}
```